# Erratic Seconds_Behind_Master

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, master-slave, slave

One of my MySQL slaves will at one moment, report 57 seconds behind master, and the next will show 0. I am also monitoring with mk-heartbeat which shows an average of less than 1 second. MySQL and system dates are correct. How exactly does MySQL calculate slave lag and what could possibly be causing this reporting error?

To be clear, running `show slave status` will report 57 seconds and running `show slave status` again (within 1 second) will show 0. This continues flopping indefinitely until the slave thread is restarted. Typically, the server would take at least 10 seconds to recover from a one minute lag.

Comment: Have you properly configured NTP?

Comment: Yes. ntp is correctly configured and time is in sync with the master.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a reporting error, that's just how MySQL replication works.  It transfers over the query log, then runs the queries.  If one of the queries take a long time to run, then all the other queries clog up until that one completes.  That's why you see the spikes.  The fact that mk-heartbeat shows a low average just means that it's not a general overload problem, just a few big queries (or, less likely, an occasional monster load spike on the slave).

Instantaneous "seconds behind master" is a fairly useless figure (except when you want to know Right Now how far behind you are).  The mk-heartbeat stats are far better for getting an idea of how overloaded your replication is -- anything higher than about 2-3 seconds on average over a dozen or so pings and you're pooched.

Comment: While this does make sense, I don't believe this is the issue. Restarting the slave thread fixed the slave lag blips, but still doesn't point to the cause.